# Is Visual Basic compatible with Android?

Tags: android, vb.net

If something is written in VB is it compatible with android?

If so, can you give me some documentation?

Comment: Do you mean classc VB or VB.Net?

Comment: How is that a relevant question?

Comment: @CamelSlack: Well, VB.NET has the possibility of being supported via Mono.  Classic VB is never likely to be supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can not use programs written in visual basic on android. Android uses java. The closest you'll get is [Mono For Android](http://android.xamarin.com/) which currently doesn't support VB.NET.

Comment: And this is one of the reasons I like C# better.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT: (7/12/2016):** This is now supported via [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform)

---

I assume you are talking about VB.NET, then Mono does not yet support it.

> Currently Mono for Android does not support Visual Basic.
>
> We are looking at adding support for Visual Basic on upcoming versions
>   of Mono for Android.
>
> Technically, what needs to happen is the following: we need to provide
>   the Visual Basic helper library (part of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)
>   and compile it to work with the Mono for Android mscorlib.dll instead
>   of the standard Mono 2.0 mscorlib.dll
>
> With the above it will be possible to use Microsoft's Visual Studio to
>   compile VB code that will run on Mono for Android. But we want to
>   support Mono's own Visual Basic compiler, but that will also require
>   the compiler to run using the Mono for Android mscorlib.dll. This is
>   not difficult, but requires time to get done and integrate into our
>   release process.
>
> At this point there is no ETA on when the above will happen.
>
> [2](http://www.basic4ppc.com/): http://mono-android.net/FAQ

You could try however [Basic4android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/) if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you're probably going to get is VB.NET via [MonoDroid](http://android.xamarin.com/Welcome), which according to their FAQ currently [does not support Visual Basic](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/142135-does-mono-for-android-support-visual-basic-).  (But they do have it on their radar at least.)

Answer (score 1):

VB is a Microsoft product.  While there are some 'nix' implementations of .Net product like Mono, Android is unlikely to support .Net mainly due to liscencing.