# Easy language to write apps for Android?

Tags: android, basic

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878865/is-visual-basic-compatible-with-android), it seems like the only way to write apps for Android is Java.

Is there really no easier languages, ideally something closer to BASIC or Python? What about [Basic4PPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic4ppc)?

Comment: That question talks about lack of support for VB.net - it does not establish that Java is the only option.  Java is the *first* and *best supported* option on Android, but many other things have been used - C officially, but also javascript (mostly within the browser engine) and to some degree or another almost everything that has an open source interpreter or compiler/code generator module available has been or will be tried by someone.  On the "making it easy" side there's also App Inventor

Comment: What's wrong with the question "Is there an easier language than Java to write Android applications"?

Comment: @ChrisStratton But no need to rag on the OP

Comment: There is not an easier language that java. I mean, if you try C, it is far harder than java. Also there are LOTs of tutorials of programming for android in java, you can check them on android webpage 

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: @JuanMendes I changed the comment when I realized someone in the referenced did state that Java was the way it's done.

Comment: More generally this is too broad a question - it's going to result in either a catalog of options or dueling recommendation opinions.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it in JavaScript with http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk and the kicker is that your app will also work for iOS

**Creating a Window**

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  title:'My Window',
  backgroundColor:'#cccccc'
});
win.open();  // open window
```

**Creating a Label**

```
var label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
  color:'#999',
  text:'Hello World',
  font:{fontSize:20},
  textAlign:'center'
});
win.add(label); // add label to window
win.open();     // open window
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, I'll see if that's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Android uses a [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) to run their apps, and does not have a compiler for Basic or Python. You would need some other system to convert your other language code to Java.</s>

I suggest finding a good java tutorial, and to bookmark [Android Development Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html) and [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), because Java is a great programming language, that runs on virtually all machines.

Do you know VB.net, because C#.net wouldn't be too much of a stretch, and C#.net is extremely similar to Java.

**Update :**

I was incorrect on Android using a Java Virtual Machine, it uses a [Dalvik Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) which takes compiled java bytecode, and converts it to a Dalvik Executable (.dex), and the .dex file is what the Dalvik Virtual Machine uses to run the application.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So it looks like it's either Java or JavaScript, but certainly not VB.Net or even BASIC.

Comment: Android **does not** have a Java Virtual Machine.  It uses a Dalvik VM as it's preferred way of running applications, and it's toolchain has a java-to-dalvik converter.  But android will also run native (arm or whatever) code (though a lot of I/O has to go through jni to code written in java).  Many interpreters and compilers have been created/adapted to run a wide variety of languages, either atop the Davlik VM or natively on the processor.  (Actually, one of those alternatives is a true Java VM, but *not* from Google)

Comment: Thanks, I had a professor who was wrong, then. Do you still suggest learning Java to write apps for Android?

Comment: Thanks. This is a bit confusing, so I'll read about the options.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about them specifically, a web search seems to indicate the existence of several 3rd-party (ie, not from Google) offerings for running Basic- and Python- written code on android devices.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I guess those tools compile the application's source code into the bytecode that the DVM will turn into .dex using a JIT.

Comment: Dex files already contain bytecode, if jit is involved he output is arm/thumb or whatever.  Dont know if these front ends output bytecode, native code or even java source - all are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please, write only native apps. Only native apps look nice. Android SDK is pretty simple.

Comment: Chances are you have run well done non-native apps without realizing it.